# Center image inside column in Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

I want to center an image that is inside a column in Foundation 5, I have a column of 8, and inside there's an image that don't fit the column, and I want the image to be centered.

Answer (score 4):

Editted because of the comment by question writter.

Just add the following css:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The margin auto on both sides makes them even, thus centering. Plus this can occur only for block displayed elements. img tags are initialy inline-block.

Comment: Sorry, I ment to say, I want to center the image, not fit it.